# Using script tag to include JavaScript in program via a CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have never seen this before. I have always included JavaScript in my HTML files. Is this jsfiddle doing it wrong or am I naïve?

http://jsfiddle.net/relly/jjwwd4mq/

CSS file in jsfiddle:

```
</style> <!-- remove this, it is just for jsfiddle --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css"> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script> 
<style>
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

I have trouble googling the issue of using a `<script>` tag in a CSS file, it gets conflated with other issues like executing JavaScript in a CSS file.

Also, what part should be removed? Just the top line? I am baffled by the `</style>` followed later by another `<style>`...

Comment: It doesn't actually include JS in CSS. If you check the CSS, it's relying on jsfiddle actually wrapping the CSS content in <style></style>. What it does is close the first style (notice the </style> at the start) put in script and then add another <style> so that jsfiddle does not have to contend with mismatched style tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently jsfiddle implements their CSS/JavaScript sections simply using `<style></style>` and `<script></script>` tags inside an HTML file.

Comment: So in my code should I remove the style tags but keep the script imports in my css file?

Comment: The intent of the author of that jsfiddle seems to be avoiding the work of adding the external scripts via the jsfiddle external resource panel. Usually the scripts are included in the HTML, but for editors such as jsfiddle, Codepen, etc, they have preference for you to use their UI instead.

Comment: The author's way of avoiding the work was pretty slick...it's sort of like SQL-injection techniques.

Comment: Jsfiddle's external resource panel is flawed: it has difficulty distinguishing between stylesheets and scripts. So I can imagine people using this trick to put script links in their fiddles to make sure everything goes right. Or meta elements, base etc.